# Is there a way to make Firefox prompt the user to load a local cached copy of a webpage if a network error occurs?

Tags: firefox

Chrome has this feature where:

> In cases in which a network error occurs, and we have a stale copy of the top level resource that was attempting to be loaded, show a button on the network error page that the user can use to load that stale copy.

<sup>Source:   https://codereview.chromium.org/207553008</sup>
[image]

Can Firefox be configured to work like that?

Comment: If all else fails and you dont get an answer here is a addon you could use [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cachemachine/)